# Get total physical memory in Python

Tags: python, linux, memory

How can I get the total physical memory within Python in a distribution agnostic fashion? I don't need used memory, just the total physical memory.

Comment: You could read `/proc/meminfo`.

Comment: `/proc/meminfo` should be available on pretty much all linux installs.

Comment: You don't need `/proc/meminfo` because [`sysconf` has the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28161352/832230).

Comment: /proc is only available when CONFIG_PROC_FS=y . True for desktops, servers, phones, not always true for embedded devices.

Comment: You rarely should care about *physical* memory (imagine for example a virtual processor thru docker etc...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Could you expand on that topic in [Why does `/proc/meminfo` show 32GB when AWS instance has only 16GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61498709/562769)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

your best bet for a cross-platform solution is to use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) package (available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)).

```py
import psutil
    
psutil.virtual_memory().total  # total physical memory in Bytes
```

Documentation for `virtual_memory` is [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory).

Comment: `mem = virtual_memory()`  and then `# total physical memory`? Sounds great

Comment: Future proofed with 2018/12/18: https://web.archive.org/web/20181228093919/https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory

Comment: int(np.round(psutil.virtual_memory().total / (1024. **3))) with a tip from @Asclepius.

Comment: total does not (always?) seem to return the total physical memory available. E.g. getting 33429086208 for a 32 GB machine. Expected (as reported by free): 34359738368

Answer (score 76):

**Using** [`os.sysconf`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sysconf) **on Linux:**

```
import os
mem_bytes = os.sysconf('SC_PAGE_SIZE') * os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES')  # e.g. 4015976448
mem_gib = mem_bytes/(1024.**3)  # e.g. 3.74
```

Note:

- `SC_PAGE_SIZE` is often 4096.
- `SC_PAGESIZE` and `SC_PAGE_SIZE` are equal.
- For more info, see [`man sysconf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf).
- For **MacOS**, as per user reports, this works with Python 3.7 but not with Python 3.8.

**Using `/proc/meminfo` on Linux:**

```
meminfo = dict((i.split()[0].rstrip(':'),int(i.split()[1])) for i in open('/proc/meminfo').readlines())
mem_kib = meminfo['MemTotal']  # e.g. 3921852
```

Comment: @sorin, `os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES')` apparently doesn't work on OS X. Although the OS X man page for [`sysconf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysconf.3.html) does make note of `_SC_PHYS_PAGES`, this seems inaccessible via Python. You may have more luck with `psutil`. Alternatively, refer to the techniques used in the answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems).

Comment: FWIW, the `os.sysconf()` approach also works with Python 3 and even under Solaris 10.

Comment: I am happy to report that it's working on MacOS X 10.13 (High Sierra) with Python 3.6.4.

Comment: `/proc/meminfo` seems not to work as expected on AWS: [Why does `/proc/meminfo` show 32GB when AWS instance has only 16GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61498709/562769)

Comment: On MacOs, works fine on Python 3.7 but not on Python 3.8.3. Getting `ValueError: unrecognized configuration name` for `os.sysconf('SC_PHYS_PAGES')`

Comment: Ideally I would want to figure out how to do this without external dependencies such as `psutil`

Comment: @NickKorostelev Why don't you see how `psutil` does it on the Mac? It's however a waste of time to invest effort figuring this out on the Mac. Or just use a real operating system such as Linux.

Answer (score 14):

Regular expressions work well for this sort of thing, and might help with any minor differences across distributions.

```
import re
with open('/proc/meminfo') as f:
    meminfo = f.read()
matched = re.search(r'^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)', meminfo)
if matched: 
    mem_total_kB = int(matched.groups()[0])
```

Comment: /proc only exists on Linux... so not cross-platform

Comment: I mistook distribution-agnostic for cross-platform... and now I see it's tagged Linux.  my bad :)

Comment: `/proc/meminfo` seems not to work as expected on AWS: [Why does `/proc/meminfo` show 32GB when AWS instance has only 16GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61498709/562769)

Comment: @JoshuaDetwiler You don't need to explicitly close files when using contexts like this. When the context (the with block) is closed the file will be with it.

Comment: Also @martin-thoma What AWS image are you using, I do not have this issue with the latest amazonlinux2.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me without any external library at Python 2.7.9

```
import os
mem=str(os.popen('free -t -m').readlines())
"""
Get a whole line of memory output, it will be something like below
['             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached\n', 
'Mem:           925        591        334         14         30        355\n', 
'-/+ buffers/cache:        205        719\n', 
'Swap:           99          0         99\n', 
'Total:        1025        591        434\n']
 So, we need total memory, usage and free memory.
 We should find the index of capital T which is unique at this string
"""
T_ind=mem.index('T')
"""
Than, we can recreate the string with this information. After T we have,
"Total:        " which has 14 characters, so we can start from index of T +14
and last 4 characters are also not necessary.
We can create a new sub-string using this information
"""
mem_G=mem[T_ind+14:-4]
"""
The result will be like
1025        603        422
we need to find first index of the first space, and we can start our substring
from from 0 to this index number, this will give us the string of total memory
"""
S1_ind=mem_G.index(' ')
mem_T=mem_G[0:S1_ind]

print 'Summary = ' + mem_G
print 'Total Memory = ' + mem_T +' MB'
```

Easily we can get the Used Memory and Free Memory

```
    """
        Similarly we will create a new sub-string, which will start at the second value. 
        The resulting string will be like
        603        422
        Again, we should find the index of first space and than the 
        take the Used Memory and Free memory.
        """
        mem_G1=mem_G[S1_ind+8:]
        S2_ind=mem_G1.index(' ')
        mem_U=mem_G1[0:S2_ind]

        mem_F=mem_G1[S2_ind+8:]
    print 'Used Memory = ' + mem_U +' MB'
    print 'Free Memory = ' + mem_F +' MB'
```

Comment: free is not installed by default on Mac