# Filter minions by memory size

Tags: salt-stack

Is it possible in Salt Stack to filter minions by memory size, but indicating value that the memory size must be greater or less than, rather than equal to? So instead of this:

```
salt -C 'G@mem_total:993' test.ping
```

I need somthing like this:

```
salt -C 'G@mem_total > 993' test.ping
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you actually can't by using the [targeting feature](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/) as it is.

First thing that comes in my mind is writing a [custom grain](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/#writing-grains).

If you only need this in one place and the value does not change often this might be a workaround:

**untested example**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from psutil import virtual_memory

def categorize_memory():
    grains = {}
    mem = virtual_memory()
    total_mem = mem.total
    if total_mem < 1024 * 999:
        grains['memory_category'] = 'low_mem_minion'
    else:
        grains['memory_category'] = 'high_mem_minion'
    return grains
```

Afterwards use it like that `salt -C 'G@memory_category:high_mem_minion' test.ping`

The code for resolving memory from within python was taken from [Get total physical memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102999/get-total-physical-memory-in-python)