# Print memory available in Python

Tags: python, memory

I'm making a **Operating System** in **Python** at the moment, just as a little project.

**However;** *I need it to print at the start of the code how much memory is available on the host system*.

I have looked this up and despite reading through walls of text, I am still unable to find anything. I have not yet attempted to compose anything because I wouldn't know where to start. I am a beginner and am relatively new to Python, so please excuse me if I sound a bit dumb.

**Any suggestion or code is welcome. Thanks.**

Comment: RAM or disk memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total physical memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102999/get-total-physical-memory-in-python)

Comment: Interestingly this would be something an Operating System would provide.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is about **RAM**, you can simply use the [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) package.

In this example I created a simple function `memory_available()`:

```
import psutil
from psutil._common import bytes2human

def memory_available():
    # Get total physical memory expressed in bytes
    total_phy_memory = psutil.virtual_memory().total

    # Convert to a more readable format
    total_phy_memory_GB = bytes2human(total_phy_memory)

    # Return total physical memory expressed in gigabytes
    return total_phy_memory_GB

print(memory_available())
```

The `psutil` package is a:

> Cross-platform lib for process and system monitoring in Python.

While `bytes2human` converts to a more readable format. In this case, **Gigabytes**.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!