# Why does `/proc/meminfo` show 32GB when AWS instance has only 16GB?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, virtualization

I wanted to log the total amount of memory (alternatively: used memory by the current process and available memory for the current process) of the currently running instance and used `/proc/meminfo`:

```
info = {
    i.split()[0].rstrip(":"): int(i.split()[1])
    for i in open("/proc/meminfo").readlines()
}
total_m = info["MemTotal"]
```

When I run it locally, it does what I expect. When I run it on a 16GB AWS instance in a Docker container it shows 32GB. Why is that the case?

(Side question: How should this be done?)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61498709/edit) your question to explain *why* you are reading `/proc/meminfo` and *what* you expect to read.

Comment: Please include a description of the host environment and where you have configured the 16GB limitation.

Answer (score -1):

> I wanted to log the size of the currently running instance

You don't define what is an instance for you. AFAIK it has a different meaning in AWS and in Docker.

> used memory by the current process

**Please define what is used memory**.

Read much more about [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). What about the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) ?

> available memory for the current process

**Please define what is available memory**. Are you aware of [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) ? What about [shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) ?

Then, read documentation related to [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You really should care about the current [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), not the entire system. Read a good [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook and the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) book, and https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

If you care about the current process, use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) thru `/proc/self/stat`

If you care about your AWS instances, there are some proprietary APIs for querying their status.

If you are automatizing some system administration tasks, you should explain which ones and why.

Notice that `/proc/meminfo` gives system-wide information and relates to [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) is adding [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) layers and so does [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) and you could have some [process migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_migration) at some virtual level.

Comment: Thank you, Basile! I need to read up on the links you gave. Right now, I don't see if this really answers my question (Btw: Why was his answer downvoted?)

Comment: "What instance": A task executed via AWS Fargate