# How big is the overhead of tracemalloc?

Tags: python, memory, tracemalloc

I would like to log in a production system the current memory usage of a Python script. AWS has [Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-ECS.html), but they are extremely well-hidden and I'm not sure how to use them properly within other dashboards / logging- and altering systems. Also, I'm not certain if the log peak memory at all.

The Python script is the production system. It is running on AWS within a Docker container and I ran into issues with a previous approach ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61498709/562769)).

[tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) seems to be able to to give me the information I want:

```
# At the start of the script
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()

# script running...

# At the end
current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
logger.info(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6} MB")
logger.info(f"Peak memory usage was {peak / 10**6} MB")
tracemalloc.stop()
```

However, the docs state:

> The tracemalloc module is a debug tool

So would it be a bad idea to wrap this around production code? How much overhead is it? Are there other reasons not to use that in production?

(I have a pretty good idea of which parts of the code need most memory and where the peak memory is reached. I want to monitor that part (or maybe rather the size of those few objects / few lines of code). The alternative to tracemalloc seems to be to use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316760/562769))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been trying to answer the same question. The best answer I've found is from

https://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg443129.html

which quotes a factor of 3-4 increase memory usage with tracemalloc based on a simple experiment.

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty bad. So definitely nothing you want in a production system. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem while working with a large dataframe and can confirm the 3-4x performance hit.

In my tests, the following snippet ran in 41-42s:

```
import pandas as pd

def preprocess():
    data = pd.read_csv('<filename>')
    # additional preprocessing logic
```

But just importing `tracemalloc` increased that time to >120s:

```
import tracemalloc
import pandas as pd

def preprocess():
    data = pd.read_csv('<filename>')
    # additional preprocessing logic
```

However, per [this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/measuring-memory-python/), you can profile resident memory with `psutil`:

```
import psutil
psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 1024**2 # B -> MiB
```

And doing so incurs no hit to performance.

Answer (score 0):

tracemalloc wraps the regular memory allocator with its own allocation function to perform additional bookkeeping for memory allocations/de-allocations.  This happens *on every memory allocation call* so if you are creating a large amount of objects, this will significantly slow down your Python code.

The 3x-4x memory size increase is likely because tracemalloc keeps a hashtable lookup of every memory allocation trace.