# How to get total heap size used heap size and mallocated memory in python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

In node.js there are libraries like `V8` and `process` for getting the heap and malloc stats. Example:

```js
const heapStats = v8.getHeapStatistics();
const heapInfo = process.memoryUsage();

console.log('Heap Total:', heapStats.heapTotal);
console.log('Heap Used:', heapStats.heapUsed);
console.log('Malloced Memory:', heapInfo.mallocedMemory);
```

Since both languages use an underlying C/C++ layer, is there any way to get these values in `python` for the current process?

Although using `memory_info()` in the `psutil` library we can get information about resident set size (rss), and physical memory used (vms), there aren't any attributes specific to heap and malloc.

We can also use `tracemalloc` to trace memory usage. However, I am not sure how to calculate the heap and malloc stats using these values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)

Comment: Also [Get total physical memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22102999/11082165)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only returns the `rss` (Resident Set Size) not stats related to heap and mallocated memory